# DataTable after row delete on next-previos page it shows again

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have strange issue with DataTables. I am using this stuff to delete row and all is working (row is deleted from DB, alerts showing properly), and it removes row from display BUT when I click previous page and come back to the page where row was displayed originally (by page I mean DataTable page number or I increase number of rows per page) - it is showing again...(as it was not actually removed)

Only after hard-refresh it is removed.  Why is this happening and how to really remove it without actually refreshing the browser?

Here is the code I am using to delete row:

```
function DeletePublisher(element, publisherid) {
jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this publisher?', 'Delete publisher', function (r) {
    if (r) $.post('includes/publishers/delete-publisher.php?publisherid=' + publisherid,

    function (data) {
        if ($.trim(data) == 'error') {
            $.jGrowl('This publisher was already deleted', {
                header: '<strong style="text-align:center;">ERROR</strong>'
            });
            $(element)
                .parents('tr')
                .remove();
        } else {
            $(element)
                .parents('tr')
                .remove();
            oTable.fnDeleteRow(element);
            $('tr')
                .removeClass();
            // Now add class names again
            $('tr:odd')
                .addClass('odd');
            $('tr:even')
                .addClass('even');

            $.jGrowl('Publisher deleted');
        }
    });
});
```

And this is TR element:

```
<td class="action-th">
                    <ul class="button-table-head">
                            <li><div class="button-head edit-icon"><a href="/includes/publishers/edit-publisher.php?editpublisher=<?php echo $publisher_id; ?>" data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="iframe sweet-tooltip" data-text-tooltip="Edit" data-style-tooltip="tooltip-mini-slick"><span>Edit</span></a></div></li>
                        <li><div class="button-head delete-icon"><a href="#" class="sweet-tooltip" data-text-tooltip="Delete" data-style-tooltip="tooltip-mini-slick" onclick="DeletePublisher(this,'<?php echo $publisher_id; ?>')"><span>Delete</span></a></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
```

So not sure if element is passing correct ID of row at the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the element from the DOM with `$(element).parents('tr').remove();`, you may want to try `fnDeleteRow` to remove the row from the Datatable as well. You can pass a parameter to the method that will tell Datatables to redraw the table which wouldn't force you to do a post back to refresh the data.

Here's [the link](http://datatables.net/api#fnDeleteRow) to `fnDeleteRow` in the Datatables API.

**UPDATE:**

Try something like this:

```
function DeletePublisher(element, publisherid) {
jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete this publisher?', 'Delete publisher', function (r) {
    if (r) $.post('includes/publishers/delete-publisher.php?publisherid=' + publisherid,

    function (data) {
        var nTr = $(element).closest('tr');

        oTable.fnDeleteRow(nTr, null, true);

        if ($.trim(data) == 'error') {
            $.jGrowl('This publisher was already deleted', {
                header: '<strong style="text-align:center;">ERROR</strong>'
            });
        } else {
            $.jGrowl('Publisher deleted');
        }            
    });
});
```

Comment: Exactly.  DataTables maintains its own copy of the underlying table data, so simply removing the visible elements from the DOM is not sufficient.

Comment: Well, I tried with: oTable.fnDeleteRow( element );  but it didn't work ?

Comment: @Peter What is `element`? According to the docs it should either be the index of the row you want to delete or the `<tr>` element of the row to be deleted. You may also need to redraw the table after deleting the row. Unless you manually redraw the table I don't think the row will show as deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very good with JS, so I will update my code above to see and let me know if element is correct variable at all.

Comment: No, this doesn't remove row at all :( ...actually it does, but after refresh

Comment: @Peter You could try adding `oTable.fnDraw()` after `oTable.fnDelete()` but in reality that's what the `true` parameter is supposed to do. Also note that I removed the bit of code where you were calling `.remove()` on the `tr` as well.

Comment: This is strange. I've tried everything and this just won't work for me. :( I've tried this as well: 
$(element).parents('tr').remove();
        var nTr = $(element).closest('tr');
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(nTr, null, true);
        oTable.fnDestroy();
 oTable.fnDraw();
        $.jGrowl('Publisher deleted');  but this also won't work plus this isn't displaying "message"... am I doing something very wrong ?

Comment: Get rid of this line: `$(element).parents('tr').remove();`. You shouldn't need it and it may be causing issues with the `nTr` variable. When Datatables gets redrawn the table rows will get updated and removed automatically.

Comment: I tried this:
var nTr = $(element).closest('tr');
        oTable.fnDeleteRow(nTr, null, true);
    $.jGrowl('Publisher deleted');
    oTable.fnDraw();  and when jGrowl popup is below fnDelete line - it doesn't show, if it's above - it shows - in both cases publisher is really deleted from DB, but ROW isn't deleted in DataTable :(